# Image path all 404 after move my remote site to localhost

Tags: 8, migrations

I just moved everything from my remote Drupal site to localhost (C:\xampp\htdocs\folder). All links (content images, menu links) are shown like `http://localhost/sites/default/files/inline-images/magento.png` when it should be `http://localhost/foldername/sites/default/files/inline-images/magento.png`.

Is there any quick method I can use to fix this problem like using mod_rewrite?

Comment: Try by uncommenting the "RewriteBase" in your .htaccess file and replace with the your project "foldername"

Comment: i had tried,  RewriteBase /foldername or RewriteBase /foldername/ or RewriteBase foldername, all useless

Comment: i don't know why the uploaded image  url is /sites/default/files/inline-images/magento.png but not sites/default/files/inline-images/magento.png, the image will be displayed if the slash is gone.

Comment: I think there is some issue with apache finding your Document Root folder. Are your running your site by setting up Virtual host name or with normal way like localhost/projectname?

Comment: the localhost i'm running xampp localhost/projectname

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Answer (score 0):

If the RewriteBase Method is not working and every other page works, try to set the $base_url variable in your settings.php file to your folder.

Comment: i'm using drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) module for solving image url issue